# Rewrite URL with different values

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like my URLs to change from
e.g.

```
website.com/contactus.php?type=buy&property=texas
website.com/contactus.php?type=sell
```

to

```
website.com/contactus/buy/texas
website.com/contactus/sell
```

respectively. This is what I have so far--

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

#rewrites to without www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [R=301]

#makes it so file types are hidden
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ - [L]
Options +MultiViews
Options -Indexes 


#makes so GET stuff are hidden
RewriteRule ^contactus/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /contactus.php?id=$1&$2 [L,QSA]
```

ive been reading countless of stack overflow questions but the bit about the GET values doesnt seem to be working at all...

-edit- thanks to anubhavas help i've managed to solve it :) Here the code, for anyone looking.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

#rewrites to without www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [R=301]

#makes it so php file types are hidden
RewriteRule ^(emailme)/?$ $1.php [L,QSA]


#makes it so GET values are hidden
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(emailme)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?type=$2&property=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(emailme)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?type=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

#rewrites to without www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [R=301]

#makes it so file types are hidden
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(contactus|emailme)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?type=$2&property=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(contactus|emailme)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?type=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that comment don't provide any info on what's not working and what's wrong. Q1. What URL did you use to test? What is location of this .htaccess and do yo have other rules there?

Comment: i provided all the rules used at the moment. the bit under 'make GET stuff hidden" wasnt working for me already :o you can see it here: http://starproperties.biz/emailme?type=buy&property=test%20test and http://starproperties.biz/emailme/buy/test%20test

Comment: It works now, but the page is a bit...strange. for one, #make file type hidden doesnt work now (see http://starproperties.biz/emailme ), and the page seems to have lost its formatting o.o

Comment: That is because your css/js links are using relative paths. Just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.